# Setter not called when a control bound to Array element changes the value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am new to WPF and bindings and I wanted to see if there is a way to do a two way binding between an array element and a control:

My ViewModel has a property  which looks like  following:

```
public ObservableCollection<MeaseurementValue> MeasurementValues
        {
            get
            {
                return Config.MeasurementValues;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == null) return;
                Config.MeasurementValues = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MeasurementValues");
                QpatConfig.SerializeConfigFile(Config,
                    Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)) + "//Qualcomm//QPAT//qpat.config");              
            }
        }
```

Where MeasurementValues is defined as following:

```
public class MeaseurementValue
    {
      public string TestName { get; set; }
      public int value { get;set; }
    }
```

Xaml looks like following:

```
 <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1"   Grid.Row="1"   Height="23" Margin="14,20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding MeasurementValues[0].value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124"  />
```

So the element in the xaml is bound to an Arrayelement in ViewModel. But when I change that property in text control it does not call the setter of the ViewModel.

I also changed my code that evey element in the array is also notifiable so it looks like following:

```
public class MeaseurementValue : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
      public string TestName { get; set; }    

      private int _value;
      public int value
      {
          get { return _value; }
          set { _value = value; OnPropertyChanged("value"); }
      }

      void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
      {
          var handler = PropertyChanged;
          if (handler != null)
          {
              handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
          }
      }
    }
```

But that also did not work

Is that anything different that we have to do with Arrays as oppose to primitive types?

Comment: Call which setter of the viewmodel? It wouldn't call the setter of `MeasurementValues` because it's not replacing the collection object.

Comment: So, if I want two way binding between Array elements and the control, how can I approach that?

Comment: It already happens. It's just that the setter of `value` would get called, because that's what is being updated.

Answer (score 2):

The setter gets called, just not the one you expect. In two-way bindings, only the last property in the path gets updated (in the target->source direction).

Think of it like this - if you wrote it in C#, what would you expect to happen?

```
MeasurementValues[0].value = 1;
```

What happens here is that first the `MeasurementValues` **getter** is called,  then the array indexer's **getter** is called, but the **setter** is of the `value` property. So there's no reason for the array's setter to ever be called. You're two property accessors away from the `MeasurementValues` setter. Even if you write

```
MeasurementValues[0] = new MeasurementValue();
```

the `MeasurementValues` setter won't be called. Only

```
MeasurementValues = new ObservableCollection<MeaseurementValue>();
```

would cause the setter you're referring to be called. It's the exact same thing with bindings. The **last** item in the property path is the only setter used in a two-way binding. In your case it's the `value` property.

If you want to save the configuration each time the `value` property is set, you can:

- Create a `ValueChanged` event in `MeaseurementValue` and hook it up when you create each item
- Use some pub/sub mechanism (such as Prism's *Event Aggregator*) to publish that the value has changed

Comment: Do you mean something that has been described here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415858/binding-to-an-array-element

Comment: Well, I changed my question to add more details. is there anything wrong with what I did?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I have implemented the ValueChanged for MeasurementValue. Is it the right implementations? I have updated answer with that.

Comment: Hey Lost, have you solved your problem? Cause i'm having the same issue