# WPF How to set an array as a property

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf

I am using WPF and I have a set number of  Ellipses whose color I want to change during run time. here is my code

```
Color[] ellipsecolor = new Color[13];
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void onPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

I wanted to do this :

```
Ellipse x:Name="Spot5" Fill="Gray" StrokeThickness="6" Width="40" 
Height="40" Margin="219,211,241,249" MouseDown="Ellipse_MouseDown"
  ..
 SolidColorBrush Color= "{Binding ellipsecolor[0],IsAsync=True}"/>
```

but I am not sure If I can even do that .
Can this be done ?

Comment: Do you have one ellipse that can change color, or 13 different ellipses all of which will have different non-changing colors?

Answer (score 1):

No need to use an array. You can index into an ObservableCollection in your xaml similar to indexing into an array. The type of your collection needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, though. Ideally, you'd create a type that inherited from Color and implement INotifyPropertyChanged, but since the Color class is sealed, that's not possible.

However, wrapping Color in your own type should work.

```
 class MyColor : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {        
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private Color _color;

        public Color color
        {
            get
            {
               return _color;
            }

            set
            {
               _color = value;
               OnPropertyChanged("color");
            }
        }

        void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
  }
```

Instantiate the collection where appropriate.

```
   ObservableCollection<MyColor> ellipseColors = new ObservableCollection<MyColor>();
```

Then bind to the color property of your indexed MyColor object in the xaml.

```
Color= "{Binding Path=ellipseColors[0].color, IsAsync=True}"/>
```

Credit to this post for some of the ideas. [Binding to an array element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415858/binding-to-an-array-element)

**Update:**

```
public partial class Wafer : UserControl
{
    private string _waferLocation;

    ObservableCollection<MyColor> ellipseColors;

    private void WaferLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      ellipseColors = new ObservableCollection<MyColor>();          

      for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
      {
          ellipseColors.Add(new MyColor { color = Brushes.Gray });               
      }

    }

    class MyColor : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private SolidColorBrush _color;

        public SolidColorBrush color
        {
            get
            {
                return _color;
            }

            set
            {
                _color = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("color");
            }
        }

        void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He's got more than one ellipse, so he can't do `[0]` in XAML.

Comment: Not sure I follow. However many ellipses there are, each one can bind to any index in the collection they want, no?

Comment: Yeah, but you're using WPF. You shouldn't be doing that. An `ItemsControl` is the proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which MVVM framework you're using, but the general approach is this:

1. In the ViewModel layer, create a VM for your ellipse:

   ```
   public class EllipseVM : ObservableObject
   {
       private Color _Color;
       public Color Color
       {
         get => _Color;
         set => Set(ref _Color, value);
       }

       private double _X;
       public double X
       {
         get => _X;
         set => Set(ref _X, value);
       }

       private double _Y;
       public double Y
       {
         get => _Y;
         set => Set(ref _Y, value);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a collection of these ellipses in your main ViewModel:

   ```
   public class MainVM : ViewModelBase
   {
       private ObservableCollection<EllipseVM> _Ellipses;
       public ObservableCollection<EllipseVM> Ellipses
       {
         get => _Ellipses;
         set => Set(ref _Ellipses, value);
       }
   }
   ```
3. In your View layer, create an `ItemsControl` that binds with this collection:

   ```
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Ellipses}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <Canvas />
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
         <Ellipse Fill="{Binding Color}" Width="40" Height="40" />
       </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

     <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
       <Style>
         <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}" />
         <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}" />
       </Style>  
     </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
   </ItemsControl>
   ```

### Points

1. You can add as many ellipses to your collection as you want at runtime. The View layer will automatically update itself since your collection is `ObservableCollection`.
2. `ItemsControl` uses `Canvas` as its panel, which allows you to position your ellipses using X,Y co-ordinates. This allows you to place or move your ellipses at runtime.
3. Note that Canvas properties need to be set through `ItemContainerStyle` and not through `ItemTemplate`. This is because `ItemsControl` generates a wrapper element for each item of your collection. Your `DataTemplate` is then placed inside that wrapper, so you need to set the position of that wrapper element, which is exactly what `ItemContainerStyle` does.
4. If your VM layer cannot use Color class (since it is a View level library), you can use set the `Color` property of EllipseVM to be of type `int`. You'll then need to create a converter in the View layer to convert `int` value to `Color`.
5. I have used helper classes from MVVM Light (e.g. `ViewModelBase` and `ObservableObject`). If you're using a different framework, replace them with their counter-parts.
6. You have to set the `DataContext` of your View to `MainVM`. You can do that through `ViewModelLocator` in MVVM Light. You can also do that directly in XAML or code-behind.

Comment: I am not using MVVM

Comment: @Nia2: OK. You should though if you're doing anything serious in WPF.